# Running a query from pyodbc takes so much longer than from SSMS

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to run a simple query on a SQL Server using pyodbc. The query seems to get stuck and or is taking forever to complete. When I run the same query from SSMS the query executes in 2 seconds. If anybody has a idea of why pyodbc is taking so long please let me know.

This is the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, MAX(v)) 
       FROM (VALUES ([INSERT_DATE]), ([LAST_MODIFIED_DATE])) AS value(v)) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1);
```

The specific table seems to be updating regularly throughout the day and I wonder if that makes pull data based on date particularly difficult.

Comment: Do you have sp_whoisactive or other monitoring tools on the server? It might provide more insight.

Comment: I will check but what are you looking for specifically?

Comment: It'll help diagnose it if it's a SQL Server issue or not. sp_whoisactive will show if it's an active session on the SQL side.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably blocking.  As written that query will always require a complete scan.  The fact that it executes in SSMS in 2 sec indicates that it's not really an expensive query.  Is it possible you have an uncommitted update to that table in another session?

You might try refactoring it to possibly use indexes, or investigate the blocking on the SQL Server.

EG

```
USE TEMPDB
GO
drop table if exists [TABLE]
go

create table [TABLE]
(
  id int primary key,
  data char(200) not null default replicate('z',200),
  INSERT_DATE datetime,
  LAST_MODIFIED_DATE datetime 
)

create index ix_T_id on [TABLE](INSERT_DATE) 
create index ix_T_lm on [TABLE](LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) 

go

with q as
(
  select top 1000000 row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
  from sys.messages m, sys.messages m2
)
insert into [TABLE] (id,insert_date,LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)
select i, dateadd(minute,-1*i,getdate()),dateadd(minute,-1*i,getdate())
from q
go

set statistics time on
go

SELECT *
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [INSERT_DATE] >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1) AND [INSERT_DATE] < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
  OR  [LAST_MODIFIED_DATE] >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1) AND [LAST_MODIFIED_DATE] < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
  /*
   SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 233 ms, elapsed time = 233 ms.
   */

  SELECT *
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, MAX(v)) 
       FROM (VALUES ([INSERT_DATE]), ([LAST_MODIFIED_DATE])) AS value(v)) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1);
/*
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1360 ms,  elapsed time = 328 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
   */
go
set statistics time off
go
```

Comment: I won't lie, I don't know much about blocking. I read about some of it here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/224453/inf-understanding-and-resolving-sql-server-blocking-problems . I guess I would like to know why it would run perfectly fine in SSMS versus python. How do I get around the blocking?